# Filtering data using Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a list of Schools `List<Schools>` and want to filer out the blacklisted schools. I want to filter out the blacklisted schools using Java 8. How should I do it. Is Java 8 streams the best way.
<Please, forgive my punctuations, some keyboard keys are not working>. Ex if `List<Schools>` contain School A, School B, School C. And BlackListed school is B. Final Result should be A and C.

```
Schools.java

public class Schools{
public String className;
public String schoolCode;
}

BlackListedSchools.java

public class BlackListedSchools
{
public School school;
public School getSchool()
{
return this.school;
}
}


public School
{
  public String className;
    public String schoolCode;
}
```

Comment: I think there are so many issues with the code you posted, it's difficult to know where to begin, so I won't. Get your keyboard keys fixed & post something comprehensible & maybe we can help you.

Comment: you should look deeper into your code. Blacklisted should not be a class on its own. It may be better to make blacklisted as the property of class School.

Comment: Please, share **your attempt** to address the problem and describe what the issues you've faced. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an **effort**, see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also fix the syntax and formatting of the classes you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have created all the required java classes as per your question.
You can use and implement the below code-***

**School.java**

```
public class School {
    
      private String schoolName;
      private String schoolCode;
    
      public School(String schoolName, String schoolCode) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
        this.schoolCode = schoolCode;
      }
    
      public String getSchoolName() {
        return schoolName;
      }
    
      public void setSchoolName(String schoolName) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
      }
    
      public String getSchoolCode() {
        return schoolCode;
      }
    
      public void setSchoolCode(String schoolCode) {
        this.schoolCode = schoolCode;
      }
    
      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "School{" +
            "schoolName='" + schoolName + '\'' +
            ", schoolCode='" + schoolCode + '\'' +
            '}';
      }
```

**BlacklistedSchool.java**

```
public class BlackListedSchool {

  private School school;

  public School getSchool() {
    return school;
  }

  public void setSchool(School school) {
    this.school = school;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "BlackListedSchool{" +
        "school=" + school +
        '}';
  }
}
```

**Test.class**

```
public class TestSchool {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    School schoolA = new School("A","A001");
    School schoolB = new School("B","B001");
    School schoolC = new School("C","C001");

    BlackListedSchool blackListedSchool = new BlackListedSchool();
    blackListedSchool.setSchool(schoolB);

    List<School> listOfSchools = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfSchools.add(schoolA);
    listOfSchools.add(schoolB);
    listOfSchools.add(schoolC);

    List<School> notBlackListedSchool =
        listOfSchools.stream().filter(sc -> !sc.getSchoolCode().equals(blackListedSchool.getSchool().getSchoolCode())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(notBlackListedSchool);

  }
}
```

**Output ::**

```
[School{schoolName='A', schoolCode='A001'}, School{schoolName='C', schoolCode='C001'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

List schools = new ArrayList<>();
BlackListedSchools B = new BlackListSchools();
List schoolRes =  schools.stream().filter(t->t.schoolCode != B.school.schoolCode).collect(Collectors.toList()